# How can i open the exe file inside the windows form ?

Tags: .net, vb.net

When i click on the `button` the `executable file` should  open inside the `form`.
I had search lots of things in net  but till now i cant get any decipherable idea.
So kindly do me needful.

Comment: What do you mean by "the executable file should open inside the form?"  Do you have a separate application that you want to (visually) appear inside your own window?

Comment: You can't do that - what are you trying to achieve maybe we can suggest an alternative?

Comment: Pinvoking SetParent() might work.  It is brittle and hard to get right.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the source and it is in .Net you can put the executable into a shared library and call the code from your window and display it however you want.  Otherwise you can run the executable outside of your windows form application calling the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exePath);
```